# Differentiability of function defined as integral form

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

Let $H(t)=\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb R}\lvert\, f(x)+tg(x)\rvert^p\mathrm dx$ and $f,g\in L^p(\Bbb R)$.

Then, how  to prove that $H$ is differentiable and find its derivative?

I think it's impossible to find it by $\dfrac{H(t+h)-H(t)}{h}$.

Should I show that $H$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: You are computing the Gateaux derivative of the $L^p$-norm. You may want to differentiate under the integral sign (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). Look also Example 13.12 of this book: http://books.google.it/books?id=oOYQVeHmNk4C&pg=PA390&lpg=PA390&dq=gateaux+derivative+Lp+norm&source=bl&ots=XKpUUh1IL6&sig=nA4GHWVY81R87nk_JP2FL4mzcLw&hl=it&sa=X&ei=ISqrUpjZOMb9ygP8g4DwDw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=gateaux%20derivative%20Lp%20norm&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{|f(x)+(t+h)g(x)|^p-|f(x)+tg(x)|^p}{h}=p|f(x)+(t+\vartheta)g(x)|^{p-1}g(x),
$$
for some $\vartheta\in(0,h)$, if $p>1$. The right-hand side is bounded by
$$
p\big(|f(t)|+s|g(t)|\big)^{p-1}|g(x)| \in L^{1}(\mathbb R),
$$
where $s\ge |t+\vartheta h|$, for all small $h$. Then use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.